# haskell parse error incorrect identation?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a program that accepts in input a matrix made by list of list such as `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` and gives as output its transpose `[[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]`.

This version works but it gives an error because it reaches the end of the list and doesn't stop.

```
transpose xxs = map head xxs : transpose (map tail xxs)
```

So I tried this one

```
transpose xxs = if ((length xxs)>0) then 
            map head xxs : transpose (map tail xxs)
```

But I get the error

> parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

So I tried writing the code without brackets, all in one line, without indentation but I didn't manage to solve this error.

I'm starting to suspect it's not a problem of brackets or spaces.

Comment: You're missing `else`. And the indentation is indeed incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't begin to guess why the compiler gives you that error message, but in Haskell, all `if/then` expressions need an `else` case as well:

```
transpose xxs =
  if (length xxs) > 0
  then map head xxs : prova (map tail xxs)
  else [[]]
```

Here I just put `[[]]` in the `else` branch, as that was the simplest thing I could think of to satisfy the compiler.

Comment: It solved the problem but I get the exception `Exception: Prelude.head: empty list`

Comment: @AleA That sounds like a new question (if it isn't a duplicate) :)